# Is annotating EJB 3.1 methods as REST a violation of the separation of concerns principle?

Tags: json, design-patterns, annotations, jax-rs, ejb-3.1

We're going to build an application with angularjs running in the client and a J2EE application providing and consuming JSON data.

Is it a bad practice to directly expose our business methods in our `@Stateless` EJBs with `javax.ws.rs` annotations, like `@path`, `@get` and other http-related ones? We're concerned that our business code would become "*impure*" if it's filled with those "web-related" imports.

Or are we just being paranoid?

Answer (score 1):

As per JavaEE reference here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html, **A stateless session bean can implement a web service**.  So, I think it should be alright to add REST annotations to Stateless EJBs to make the functionality available as a web service

> **Stateless Session Beans**
>
> A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with
>   the client. When a client invokes the methods of a stateless bean, the
>   bean’s instance variables may contain a state specific to that client
>   but only for the duration of the invocation. When the method is
>   finished, the client-specific state should not be retained. Clients
>   may, however, change the state of instance variables in pooled
>   stateless beans, and this state is held over to the next invocation of
>   the pooled stateless bean. Except during method invocation, all
>   instances of a stateless bean are equivalent, allowing the EJB
>   container to assign an instance to any client. That is, the state of a
>   stateless session bean should apply across all clients.
>
> Because they can support multiple clients, stateless session beans can
>   offer better scalability for applications that require large numbers
>   of clients. Typically, an application requires fewer stateless session
>   beans than stateful session beans to support the same number of
>   clients.
>
> **A stateless session bean can implement a web service**, but a stateful
>   session bean cannot.

Comment: I personally like the approach.  It fits well with the EJB programming paradigm, in that it forces the container to start a transaction when the request comes in and either commit or rollback on failure.  I don't put any BL into the SLSBs instead I delegate to some CDI controller objects.

Comment: @wand-maker, just because it "_can implement a web service_" it doesn't follows that it's a good practice to do so.

Comment: @bruno Well, thinking hard about every mundane decision is also not a good practice. Sometimes, its better to take a path and learn & do course correction than sitting in a place wondering which path to take.  The phrase "good practice" has become quite dreadful, and I feel its better to help fellow developers to make some decisions with more comport

Comment: Sorry to 'resurrect' this old thread, but I have just encountered this question many times during my OCMJEA preparation. There is infact this specific question in the exam. The answer is: yes you can do, and it works, if your needs is to quickly expose your business logic, but it is not a best practice. All the WS should belong to the Integration Layer side.